# Smarty - call a function and render the response

Tags: templates, smarty

On a current website, i'm trying to execute a function, that comes from a variable.

My current code snippet:

```
<textarea rows="10" name="{$field.name}" class="form-control">{$field.placeholder}</textarea>
```

So, what is inside the placeholder variable?

```
{$plugin->getMessage()}
```

And the content from my textarea is currently with this setup:

```
{$plugin->getMessage()}
```

But the goal is, that smarty executes the function and use the CONTENT, that returns from the function. So i've tried to use some filters.

- First i used `"ldelim"` and `"rdelim"`

  ```
  {ldelim}{$field.placeholder}{rdelim}
  ```

The response in my browser was (Value inside the textarea):

```
{{$plugin->getMessage()}}
```

- Also i've tried using `"literal"`

  ```
  {literal}{$field.placeholder}{/literal}
  ```

The response in my browser (Value inside the textarea):

```
{$field.placeholder}
```

But what should i use, to get the response of my function `"$plugin->getMessage()"`?

EDIT:
For someone else, who has the same problem as well: Use `{eval var=$foo}`

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.eval.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may be confused on how smarty works. Seems that you're just assigning a string "{$plugin->getMessage()}" to a variable $field.placeholder, and expect that, somehow, smarty will eval it. But it does not, so that's why it shows the string instead.

To make it work you should assign in your php script the result of that function to a variable

Comment: Yeah, i am a little bit confused, because in TWIG you are able to re-parse a variable content by using `|raw`. So the function i've called inside the variable as string is executing one more time, and returns the functions result. And i really doubt, smarty can not do that, too.

Comment: Well, smarty has {eval} - http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.eval.tpl, don't know if it works like twig raw, but you can give it a try

Comment: That is exactly what i'm looking for! Thank you very much.